# How to schedule email newsletter

Tags: kentico

How to schedule an email newsletter? Documentation seems to missing that. I have newsletter with widget that will take news from last 2 weeks. I would like to automatically send that newsletter every 2 weeks.
Kentico 11

Answer (score 0):

Re-sending newsletters based on some interval (e.g every week) is not supported in Kentico at this time. It is possible through some customization, however.

By scheduling a newsletter to be sent at some time in the future, a scheduled task is created in the Scheduled Tasks application (under your site > System Tasks). This task only runs **once** and is then deleted, but you can alter the configuration of the task to run periodically and not delete itself. Or, you can manually create a task that uses **CMS.Newsletters.QueueSender** and TaskData equal to the issue's GUID.

There is another issue to solve once the task has been scheduled to run periodically- the issue's **IssueStatus** will be changed to **Finished** (5) after it is sent the first time, but the QueueSender will only re-send the issue if the status is **ReadyForSending** (1).

You can use an object event handler or custom scheduled task to automatically change the IssueStatus to 1 before the issue is sent once again.